# grails performance optimization

Tags: hibernate, grails

for the application I am working on I have to generate consolidated report where application have to read very large volume of data, some time in the order of over 100,000 records from database. What we are finding is using grails/hibernate (which we are using as defacto ORM for the entire application) is not performing well. In certain cases even to query result set as small as 10,000 records it takes 1.3+ sec. Wondering if there is any tuning I am missing or if its better to move to native sql for such requirements.

Just to mention the table is very simple and in there are no joins. The only reason I prefer to go with Hibernate as criterion's to filter data is very dynamic and spawns multiple optional columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out this link.  Very insightful.  Guy shows how he went from loading 100K record from over 2hrs to just 3 minutes.
http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/

Comment: We actually looked at that and did the gorm cleanup every 100 rows.  It worked great and we could turn it off and go from 40 minute load to 6 minute loads.  A week later we tried it again and it stopped working and not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Are you querying the database to bring 100,000 records to the middle tier so you can do calculations for that report?  If the answer is yes, I'd consider a stored procedure or view for that report so you can do the calculations on the database server and reduce the amount of data and processing when you generate the report.

Check your schema to make sure you have indexes on all columns in WHERE clauses, including foreign keys.  Get the generated SQL from Hibernate and to EXPLAIN PLAN to see where the time is being spent.

This is one issue that people have with Hibernate: what to do when the generated SQL isn't performant enough.  You might have to resort to something else, like straight JDBC or iBatis, if Hibernate can't do the job.

Comment: Using hibernate can I limit the column names ? i.e. instead of returning all columns, I think if I reduce data coimg back that might help performance as well

Comment: You can use HQL, but the problem is that it'll still refer to your ORM mapping.